# VBA scraping tr onclick

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Below is the html/javascript code: I want to scrape the id in the tr tag onclick. How can I scrape the onClick tag and just acquire the id at the end? The code below is for a dynamic secure website table which all rows are hyperlinked and sorted in odd and even class as you will see below. I appreciate any help, thank you!

```
<tr class='odd' onmouseover='mov(this)' onMouseOut="mou(this, 'odd')" onClick='location.href="custlist.php?rptname=Report&custm_id=**13857**"'> 
<td align='right'>&nbsp;1.&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:;'>&nbsp;Company&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:;'>&nbsp;blah blah&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:;'>&nbsp; bbb&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:right;'>&nbsp;1,084,771.10&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:right;'>&nbsp;1,060,787.10&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:right;'>&nbsp;1,203,000.00&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:right;'>&nbsp;30,233.90&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:left;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr  class='even'  onmouseover='mov(this)' onMouseOut="mou(this, 'even')" onClick='location.href="custlist.php?rptname=report&custm_id=22012"'>
<td align='right'>&nbsp;2.&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:;'>&nbsp;T3 bbhj &nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:;'>&nbsp;hhht &nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap style='text-align:right;'>&nbsp;720,260.00&nbsp;</td>


<tr>
```

*After 25 rows it states the wrap code:

```
            <tr class='header'>

  <th width='20px'>&nbsp;</th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=1&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              CUSTOMER</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=2&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              CUSTOMER AGENT</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=3&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              ACCT MANAGERS</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=4&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              TOTAL</a>
          &nbsp;<img src='images/up_arrow.gif'>&nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=5&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              BALANCE</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=6&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              CREDIT LIMIT</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=7&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              CREDIT AVAILABLE</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>


      <th nowrap>&nbsp;



          <a href='/fats/custlist.php?srid=4969&sort=8&desc=ASC&perpage=ALL' class='sorter'>
              NOTES</a>
          &nbsp;


      </th>
```

My VBA Code so far:

```
Sub GetCreditLimit()



Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject


Dim td As Object
Dim tr As Object

Dim objTbl As Object
Dim htmlTR As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlTD As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim i As Integer
Dim Links As Object
Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement
Dim n As Integer
Dim elems As Object
Dim e As Object




'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True



'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "https://brokerage.suntecktts.com/agents/login"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.agent_login.Value = "username"
.agent_password.Value = "password"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "https://brokerage.suntecktts.com/fats/custlist.php?srid=8897&page=1&perpage=ALL"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table's id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("general-report-wrapper")



'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
clip.PutInClipboard

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
Rows("1:1").Select

End If

With ieApp
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy Or Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

Set objTbl = ieDoc.getElementById("report name")
Set htmlTR = objTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Set htmlTD = htmlTR.getElementsByTagName("td")
Set td = ieDoc.getElementByTagName("td")

    For Each tr In htmlTD
      ActiveSheet.Range("J2" & Rows.count).Value = tr.onclick
            i = i + 1


    Next tr






ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing
'close 'er up

End Sub
```

Comment: @whitney, When the user clicks on the <tr> it immediately moves to the next page (custlist.php). You can get a custm_id from the query string from custlist.php page load event

Comment: please share your attempt at coding this and explain where you are stuck? Also, ensure that your html is properly formed and do not alter it.

Comment: @QHarr I added my vba code so far...its the end part getting the id from onClick I get stuck in.

Comment: @QHarr I figured it out see my answer below...Thank you so much! You're help was much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't appear to be formed properly. With properly formed HTML you should be able to use a combination of css selectors to target the element by combining a class selector, to target the `odd` class of the `tr`, with attribute = value selector, using contains (*) modifier to stipulate the `onclick` attribute value must contain the substring `custm_id`. You then extract the `onclick` attribute value string and use `Split` to access the id. Assuming Internet Explorer as access method:

```
Dim val As String
val = ie.document.querySelector("tr.odd[onClick*='custm_id']").getAttribute("onclick")
Debug.Print Split(Split(val, "custm_id=")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
```

---

All ids

```
Dim ids As Object, i As Long, val As String
Set ids = ie.document.querySelectorAll("tr[onClick*='custm_id']")

For i = 0 To ids.Length - 1
    val = ids.Item(i).getAttribute("onclick")
    Debug.Print Split(Split(val, "custm_id=")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
Next
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187610/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-vba-scraping-tr-onclick).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...see code below:

```
Sub GetCredit()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject
Dim internetdata As Object
Dim ieResult As Object
Dim header_links As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim ieTag As Object
Dim b As Object
Dim td As Object
Dim tr As Object
Dim NewURL As String
Dim iRow As Integer


    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.Navigate "https://brokerage.suntecktts.com/agents/login"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

    'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
    With ieDoc.forms(0)
        .agent_login.Value = "username" 'id
        .agent_password.Value = "password" 'password
        .submit
    End With
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    ieApp.Navigate "https://brokerage.suntecktts.com/fats/custlist.php?srid=3691&page=1&perpage=ALL"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table's id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("general-report-wrapper")



'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
clip.PutInClipboard

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
Rows("1:1").Select

End If

Dim y As Integer



Dim LR As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & LR)



With ieApp
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

Dim ids As Object, i As Long, val As String
Set ids = ieDoc.querySelectorAll("tr[onClick*='custm_id']")
Debug.Print ids



For i = 0 To ids.Length - 1
val = ids.Item(i).getAttribute("onclick")
Debug.Print val
Debug.Print Split(Split(val, "custm_id=")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Offset(i, y).Value = val
    y = y
Next i
    i = i + 1







'close 'er up
    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing








End With


End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr yes your answer...disregard previous comment it does run all ids but I need to remove duplicate headers....can you help me with that?

Comment: @QHarr yes when it imports to excel the table duplicates the header....how do I remove them? I will accept your answer now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are using the clipboard which presumably has the header repeated within that. Options: alter the html to remove that header before pasting; delete the row in the sheet if possible for one of the headers (you can target using .Find if you know one of the header values); write the table out without using clipboard and use a loop to exclude one of the headers. Can you pastebin.com the table html (I assume that is the problem section)?